# Javascript code running fine until put into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have taken some source code [from here](http://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery) to submit a form using AJAX. The form is basically taking some information from a user and putting it into a database via PHP. The code I have works, but given that what I am working on has many forms all doing the same thing, I - obviously - want to make sure my code is lean and mean.  So, making sure that each of my form field names have the same as my database with some matching IDs for various parts of the form for user feedback, have changed it to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  // process the form
  $('#formId').submit(function(event) { // for the specified form:

  //  completeForm('#formId'); // WHERE I CALL THE FUNCTION

// FUNCTION STARTS HERE WHEN IT IS ONE

    var formData = {}; formId = '#formId';

    $(formId + ' input, ' + formId + ' select, ' + formId + ' textarea').each(
      function(index){    // for each item (input, select, textarea in the specified form
        var input = $(this);
        // First, clear any existing formatting that has been added by previous form inputs
        $('#' + input.attr('id') + '-group').removeClass('has-info has-error has-success bg-error bg-info bg-success');

        // Next, add data to the array of data to pass to the PHP script
        Array.prototype.push.call(formData, input.val());

      }
    ); // End of loop through each item.

    // Now the data is collected, call the requested PHP script via AJAX.
    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
      url : $(this).attr('action'),  // '/processing/general_settings_processing.php', // the url where we want to POST
      data : formData, // our data object
      dataType : 'html' // 'json' // what type of data do we expect back from the server
    })
    // using the done promise callback
    .done(function(data) {

      // log data to the console so we can see
      console.log(data);

      // Return success and error messages to the user
      // Code to come once the basics have been sorted out!

    });
// FUNCTION WOULD END HERE WHEN IT IS ONE.
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

The code as above works absolutely fine; the relevant PHP file is called and - although I have no processing done in this particular file yet - does its stuff (I have it echoing the $_POST array to a file and returning to view in the console log atm).

However, when I try and make it a function, it doesn't - the console log simply echoes out the source code for this document instead of the PHP array that it supposed to be doing. The function is placed above the `$(document).ready` line; specified as `function completeForm(formID) { . . . }` , contains the section of code as noted in the comments and called in the commented out line as shown. So, logically (to me) it should work.

The ultimate idea is to have the function to do this in a file that can be called by all the forms that call it, while the code to call the function is in the relevant part of the page. Some pages will have more than one form using it. (I mention that should even if what I am doing here works, it wouldn't when I come to reuse the code!)

(I'm relatively new to JS and JQuery, although have a fairly good grasp of some programming techniques, mainly these days just in PHP.)

Comment: I feel I should add that the gathering of the data from the form is working fine when it is called in the function, it is simply the code that calls the PHP via AJAX that doesn't seem to want to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having with making that a function is you forget to include the "thisBinding". As a result, when you tried to use the form's action target in your ajax call with this code:

```
url : $(this).attr('action')
```

it does not find an "action" attribute - basically the issue is that `this` is actually `window` and as a result there is no action attribute. Simply bind `this` to your function call and your code will work as written.

```
completeForm.call(this,'#formId');
```

[.call <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: Simple as that, hey? That works fine and works as expected plus including the function in a separate .js file.

I don't think I thought about the 'this' call; when I first saw your answer I then thought that maybe it would play up with multiple forms before seeing sense in that! This'll teach me to be coding on a Friday night...!

Comment: @RichardGraham - Haha :) Glad it worked out for you, sometimes these are quick fixes, sometimes not. Gotta take our wins where we can get them!